# Imported image looks good in Inkscape but pixelated in the exported PDF

Tags: inkscape, pdf, export, visual-artifacts

I want to import some images into my design. I have removed the background in Gimp and when I import them into Inkscape they look almost fine:

[image]

But when I export as PDF they are pixelated:

[image]

What you see is a screenshot of both. What is the problem and how I can solve it?

P.S. These are the settings when exporting as PDF:

> Restrict to PDF version: PDF 1.5
>
> Text output options: Embed Fonts
>
> Rasterize filter effects: no
>
> Resolution for rasterization(dpi): 396
>
> Output page size: Use document page size

Comment: What happens if you put a solid color behind the images, does it still look that bad? What PDF settings are you using to export?

Comment: @Luciano I added the settings. I also added the back ground in gimp. still pixelated :(

Comment: I had to clean it up manually. I used the select by color tool in Gimp and isolated the small imperfections around. and then brushed white on them. Then used smudge tool to soften the sharpness. I seems Inkscape has issues with removed background pngs!